# GWT push button with text and image combination

Tags: gwt

Does anybody know of a way to make a push button with text on top of an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as far as I understand after some investigation, the only way is to implement own CustomButton.

Answer (score 0):

Regular HTML `<button>`s don't support adding images to them. You'll have to use a regular `<div>` with a background image and text, styled to look like a button.

Comment: I'm refering to GWT push button http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomButton it uses images. Also it can use text labels instead. But I wonder is there easy way to combine image and text on that, without implementing own custom button.

Comment: Just use a `PushButton` with text, and use CSS to add the image.